# Two nonsingular non-isomorphic modules with isomorphic injective hulls

Tags: modules

Let $R$ be a ring with unity. Are there two nonsingular non-isomorphic right $R$-modules with isomorphic injective hulls?!.

Comment: What is a nonsingular module?

Comment: I don't know what non-singular means either but perhaps one can start with a non-singular non-injective module. If its injective hull is also non-singular we see that the answer is yes.

Comment: It usually means the only element $m\in M$ such that $\mathrm {ann}(m)$ is an essential (right/left, depending) ideal of $R$ is $m=0$.

Comment: In that case doesn't $R=M=\mathbb{Z}$ and $N=\mathbb{Q}$ provide an example?

Comment: Or is the question if there is a ring $R$ where there is no example? If so, then any field should work.

Comment: @SimonWadsley That example works as well. (My mind always drifts to ideals first but trying abelian groups first would make a lot of sense!) You should make it a solution.

Comment: This example is fine and I myself thought of it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a field $F$ and  $R=\prod_{i\in \mathbb N} F$ and $I=\bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb N} F$.

$R$ and $I$ are both nonsingular as right $R$ modules because $R$ is right Rickart, meaning the annihilator of each element is a summand of $R_R$.

Furthermore $I_R$ is essential in $R_R$, and $R_R$ is an injective module.  So, $I_R$ and $R_R$ are clearly nonisomorphic, while their injective hulls are equal.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But Simon's example is simpler.